# Cannot run Android app through adb or Appium server because of SecurityException: Permission Denial

Tags: android, appium, securityexception

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent {
>   flg=0x10000000
>   cmp=com.cisco.webex.meetings/.ui.premeeting.welcome.WelcomeActivity }
>   from null (pid=19756, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10209

I have added App package and App activity names to desired capabilities. I have checked for correct App activity on APK info App, There is more than one app activity available. Which app activity I should select. Below are my desired capabilities. Can you anyone suggest a workaround for this?

```
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability("deviceName", "SM-G950U");
    cap.setCapability("udid", "988d91474b4e373156");
    cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.0.0");          
    cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.samsung.android.calender");
    cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.calender.LaunchActivity");
    cap.setCapability("waitForQuiescence", false);
    cap.setCapability("shouldUseSingletonTestManager", false);
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "uiautomator2");
    cap.setCapability("JSONSource", true);
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, false);
    cap.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions","true");
    cap.setCapability("noReset", "true");  

    URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");

    driver = new AppiumDriver<MobileElement>(url, cap);


    System.out.println("Application Started....");
```

Comment: make sure the appActivity you provided is MainAppActivity

Comment: I had tried with that as well but no luck.

Comment: remove these lines
 cap.setCapability("waitForQuiescence", false);
    cap.setCapability("shouldUseSingletonTestManager", false);
 cap.setCapability("JSONSource", true);
also make sure appium is installed as global